SwiftUI View not updating after modifying ObservedRealmObject property
I have following Realm objects - Make that holds list of Models.
class Make: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var models: RealmSwift.List<Model>
}

class Model: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var flag: Bool = false
    @Persisted(originProperty: "models") var make: LinkingObjects<Make>
}

I have a following view that fetches all the Makes and presents them in a list.
Tapping on a given Make opens a sheet with list of it's models or pushes same view on the current NavigationStack depending on Section(this if only to show the difference)
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Make.self) private var makes
    
    @State private var selected: Make?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(makes) { make in
                        Text(make.name)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selected = make
                            }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    ForEach(makes) { make in
                        NavigationLink {
                            MakeView(make: make)
                        } label: {
                            Text(make.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selected) { make in
                MakeView(make: make)
            }
        }
    }
}

MakeView has a list of it's models and tapping on the model opens another view where we can edit the name of the model
struct MakeView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var make: Make
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(make.models) { model in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditModelView(model: model)
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(model.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: model.flag ? "checkmark.circle" : "x.circle")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And finally the EditModelView that allows us to edit the Model object
struct EditModelView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField(text: $model.name) {
                Text("Name")
            }
            Toggle("Flag", isOn: $model.flag)
        }
    }
}

The problem here is that if I present MakeView through the .sheet and go to EditViewModel if I change value in TextField or Toggle and go back to previous view (MakeView) the change is not present, well actually only one change is present. If I change one letter in Name field it will be changed but any next letter will not appear, it's better visible on the Toggle when only one change in value will be reflected and any subsequent changes will not be visible. If I close MakeView and open it again the change is there. So the database is updated correctly, but the view does not update after changes to the Model name of flag are made.
This problem does not occur if the MakeView is pushed onto NavigationStack.
From my understanding the ObservedObject should track the changes and update the views accordingly.
I'm still fairly new with SwiftUI so I'm not sure if this is a bug on RealmSwift side or my inexperience and not understanding how this should be implemented.

Can you try something? It may not have any impact but can you change the EditModelView code to look like the code in Update and Objects Properties - with Text("Name") followed by TextField("Model Name", text: $model.name). And change the Form to VStack. Report back your findings.

I tried your suggestion, but it did not help. Still the same problem occurs.

I copied and pasted the code in your question into a new project. I added a button I could click on to populate some data into Realm and that was the only change. When I run the app and click on a make, which then shows a model - I  click on the > which then takes me to a sheet where I can edit the name (there's a text field and a Flag toggle). I then edit the name and then tap the Back button, the name is changed. So - your code is working for me.

Did you use first or second section? First section, the one that uses .onTapGesture to show .sheet does not work. Second section that uses NavigationLink does is in fact work and I included it to demonstrate the difference.

There's a few solutions but the issue is the view was not refreshing (and there is no way to dismiss the sheet as-is (which needs to be added). So this is an answer based on the code in the question, but there are many others.
Try changing your code to the following (I removed the working code section)
                Section {
                    ForEach(makes) { make in
                        Text(make.name)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selected = make
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selected,
                   onDismiss: didDismiss) { make in
                MakeView(make: make)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                selected = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func didDismiss() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
    }

Please review the ForEach initializer as well
The instance only reads the initial value of the provided data and doesn’t need to identify views across updates. To compute views on demand over a dynamic range, use ForEach/init(_:id:content:).
